# How do you enter the command line of a headless virtual machine on a headless server?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, arch-linux, headless

I am running a server on Arch Linux that I would like to divide into a few virtual machines using Virtual Box.  Both the server and the VM are headless machines, and both will be running Arch Linux.  I've created the VM following the guide available from Oracle (my guest OS is different, so the settings are slightly different) and the documentation provided:

- Guide: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vboxheadless
- Docs: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvm-networking

**Setup**

Create the VM:

input:

```
vboxmanage createvm --name test --basefolder vm --ostype Arch_Linux64 --register
```

Establish a network connection:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm test --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 eth0 --nicpromisc1 allow-all --bridgeadapter1 eno1
```

Create the hard drive:

```
vboxmanage createhd --filename vm/testhd.vdi --size 5000 --variant Fixed
```

Add an IDE controller:

```
vboxmanage storagectl test --name "IDE Controller" --add ide
```

Attach the HD:

```
vboxmanage storageattach test --storagectl "IDE Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium vm/testhd.vdi
```

Attach the Arch Linux iso:

```
vboxmanage storageattach test --storagectl "IDE Controller" --port 0 --device 1 --type dvddrive --medium archlinux.iso
```

Activate VRDE:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm test --vrde on
```

**VM Results**

Once completed, this is the machine as described by Virtual Box:

```
vboxmanage showvminfo test

Name:                        test
Groups:                      /
Guest OS:                    Arch_Linux64
UUID:                        c501670b-5b2d-451b-bcd8-b3c66845bf97
Config file:                 /home/eric/.config/VirtualBox/vm/test/test.vbox
Snapshot folder:             /home/eric/.config/VirtualBox/vm/test/Snapshots
Log folder:                  /home/eric/.config/VirtualBox/vm/test/Logs
Hardware UUID:               c501670b-5b2d-451b-bcd8-b3c66845bf97
Memory size                  128MB
Page Fusion:                 disabled
VRAM size:                   8MB
CPU exec cap:                100%
HPET:                        disabled
CPUProfile:                  host
Chipset:                     piix3
Firmware:                    BIOS
Number of CPUs:              1
PAE:                         enabled
Long Mode:                   enabled
Triple Fault Reset:          disabled
APIC:                        enabled
X2APIC:                      disabled
Nested VT-x/AMD-V:           disabled
CPUID Portability Level:     0
CPUID overrides:             None
Boot menu mode:              message and menu
Boot Device 1:               Floppy
Boot Device 2:               DVD
Boot Device 3:               HardDisk
Boot Device 4:               Not Assigned
ACPI:                        enabled
IOAPIC:                      enabled
BIOS APIC mode:              APIC
Time offset:                 0ms
RTC:                         local time
Hardware Virtualization:     enabled
Nested Paging:               enabled
Large Pages:                 disabled
VT-x VPID:                   enabled
VT-x Unrestricted Exec.:     enabled
Paravirt. Provider:          Default
Effective Paravirt. Prov.:   None
State:                       powered off (since 2020-07-26T14:50:34.000000000)
Graphics Controller:         VBoxVGA
Monitor count:               1
3D Acceleration:             disabled
2D Video Acceleration:       disabled
Teleporter Enabled:          disabled
Teleporter Port:             0
Teleporter Address:          
Teleporter Password:         
Tracing Enabled:             disabled
Allow Tracing to Access VM:  disabled
Tracing Configuration:       
Autostart Enabled:           disabled
Autostart Delay:             0
Default Frontend:            
VM process priority:         default
Storage Controller Name (0):            IDE Controller
Storage Controller Type (0):            PIIX4
Storage Controller Instance Number (0): 0
Storage Controller Max Port Count (0):  2
Storage Controller Port Count (0):      2
Storage Controller Bootable (0):        on
IDE Controller (0, 0): /home/eric/vm/testhd.vdi (UUID: 628a95cf-f6c2-4c6a-8c14-6c64e8fd4512)
IDE Controller (0, 1): /home/eric/archlinux.iso (UUID: 4b760f28-1e86-44b9-98b3-146728a9077f)
NIC 1:                       MAC: 080027CC8BB8, Attachment: Bridged Interface 'eno1', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: allow-all, Bandwidth group: none
NIC 2:                       disabled
NIC 3:                       disabled
NIC 4:                       disabled
NIC 5:                       disabled
NIC 6:                       disabled
NIC 7:                       disabled
NIC 8:                       disabled
Pointing Device:             PS/2 Mouse
Keyboard Device:             PS/2 Keyboard
UART 1:                      disabled
UART 2:                      disabled
UART 3:                      disabled
UART 4:                      disabled
LPT 1:                       disabled
LPT 2:                       disabled
Audio:                       enabled (Driver: ALSA, Controller: AC97, Codec: STAC9700)
Audio playback:              disabled
Audio capture:               disabled
Clipboard Mode:              disabled
Drag and drop Mode:          disabled
VRDE:                        enabled (Address 0.0.0.0, Ports 3389, MultiConn: off, ReuseSingleConn: off, Authentication type: null)
Video redirection:           disabled
OHCI USB:                    disabled
EHCI USB:                    disabled
xHCI USB:                    disabled

USB Device Filters:

<none>

Bandwidth groups:  <none>

Shared folders:<none>

Capturing:                   not active
Capture audio:               not active
Capture screens:             0
Capture file:                /home/eric/.config/VirtualBox/vm/test/test.webm
Capture dimensions:          1024x768
Capture rate:                512kbps
Capture FPS:                 25kbps
Capture options:             

Guest:

Configured memory balloon size: 0MB
```

and

```
vboxmanage guestproperty enumerate test

Name: /VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxVerExt, value: 6.1.0, timestamp: 1595776246189995001, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
Name: /VirtualBox/VMInfo/ResumeCounter, value: 0, timestamp: 1595776246170655000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
Name: /VirtualBox/HostGuest/SysprepExec, value: , timestamp: 1595776246170655000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
Name: /VirtualBox/HostGuest/SysprepArgs, value: , timestamp: 1595776246170655000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
Name: /VirtualBox/VMInfo/ResetCounter, value: 0, timestamp: 1595776246170655000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
Name: /VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxRev, value: 135406, timestamp: 1595776246189995002, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
Name: /VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxVer, value: 6.1.0, timestamp: 1595776246189995000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
```

**Running the VM**

I have tried activating the VM using:

```
vboxmanage startvm test --type headless
```

output

```
Waiting for VM "test" to power on...
VM "test" has been successfully started.
```

and

```
vboxheadless --startvm test
```

output

```
Oracle VM VirtualBox Headless Interface 6.1.0
(C) 2008-2019 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.
```

**Where I'm Stuck**

At this point, the machine appears to be running, but I cannot access it through SSH or any Remote Desktop.  Does anyone know what is going on here?  Arch Linux is a pretty hands on install process, so I need to be able to actually enter the VM environment and set up the rest of the machine.  How do I get in?

Thanks!

Comment: You enabled VRDE, do you get any error message when connecting to the host via RDP?

Comment: @RSchulze I get a connection timeout.  Also, I believe one of the two start commands should say "listening on port 3389", but I get no such message there either.